# Beaver lodges and burrows

Tags: combinations

> In the below diagram, A, B, C, D, E, F are beaver lodges and the segments in blue and red are burrows that connect the lodges. The dots marked with the letters G to S are crossing points where the beavers can change track. In the lodge A there are 3 beavers who want to reach their lodges in B, C and D. Obviously each beaver can follow several alternative paths to reach its lodge. According to the number of different paths that each beaver can follow, we will reward each with a corresponding number of apples. Each path consists of several burrows between the crossing points (the lodges in A to F can also be crossing points). A beaver can choose a specific burrow only if its ending crossing point is closer to its destination lodge, with respect to its point of origin. How many apples will each beaver gain?[Lodges and burrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB05F.png)
>   [image]

It's really confusing; I can hardly understand the terms. 
Can anyone help?

For example, from A to B I think it is AB, AOB, ANOB, AOPB, ANOPB.

Comment: Can someone edit the post so that the image is shown without having to click on the link? Thank you! I am new here!

Comment: Thank you saulspatz!!

Comment: I think the problem is stated badly.  English is my native language, and I'm not sure what "A beaver can choose a specific burrow only if its ending crossing point is closer to its destination lodge, with respect to its point of origin," means.  I imagine "with respect to" is supposed to mean "than," but I can't swear to it.  Also, does "choose a specific burrow" mean "change direction at a specific burrow?"  If so, I don't think AOB is valid, because O is the same distance from A and B, so the beaver can't change direction there.  (cont.)

Comment: > Also, ANOB and ANOPB are invalid since N is closer to A than B.  AOPB looks okay, as does AOPQB.  This is all based on a shaky interpretation of the question though.  Where does the question come from, by the way?

Comment: @saulspatz apologies, English is not my native language! The point is the following: Each time we choose a segment (burrow), we compare the distance of its ending point (in our case, we start from A and want to reach B through O) from the destination point, with respect to the previous point. Haha sorry, it is confusing! In simpler words: We start from A. Then go to O. The distance OB is smaller from the distance AB; that is, we are closer to B. And we do this for every segment that is part of a path we choose.

Comment: Same also for ANB: This path is valid, because N is closer to B, in respect to the previous point (A).

Comment: I apologize.  I didn't realize this was your translation.  I thought you were just repeating the question as it had been given to you.  I didn't intend any criticism.

Comment: I think perhaps what you want to say is, "He can only go to a burrow if it brings him closer to his goal."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm attempting to solve for one of the beavers, just to see if I've figured it out :)

All in all, it is a graph traversal problem which you can solve with [backtracking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). I believe that he problem is NP complete, so you'll need an algorithm to count them all. I have implemented the graph and a depth-first search algorithm in python. It turns out that I was underestimating very much!

- Beaver 1: A$\to$B gets 5 apples
- Beaver 2: A$\to$C gets 41 apples
- Beaver 3: A$\to$D gets 121 apples
  Enjoy!

## Python simulation

Import required packages

```
import numpy as np
```

Define the graph

```
nodes = {
  "A": [-np.sqrt(3)/2, -1/2], "B": [0,-1], "C": [np.sqrt(3)/2, -1/2], "D": [np.sqrt(3)/2, 1/2], "E": [0,1],
  "F": [-np.sqrt(3)/2, 1/2], "S": [1/np.sqrt(3),0], "J": [np.sqrt(3)/4, 1/4], "L": [-np.sqrt(3)/4, 1/4],
  "I": [1/(2*np.sqrt(3)) , 1/2], "K": [-np.sqrt(3)/4 , 1/4], "G": [-1/(2*np.sqrt(3)), 1/2], "H": [0, 1/2],
  "Q": [1/(2*np.sqrt(3)), -1/2], "N": [-np.sqrt(3)/4, -1/4], "M": [-1/np.sqrt(3),0], "P": [0, -1/2],
  "R": [np.sqrt(3)/4, -1/4], "O": [-1/(2*np.sqrt(3)), -1/2], "K": [0,0],
}

edges = [
  ["A","B"], ["A","O"], ["A",'N'], ['A','M'], ['A','F'], ['B','O'],
  ['B','P'], ['B','Q'], ['B','C'], ['C','Q'], ['C','R'], ['C','S'],
  ['C','D'], ['D','E'], ['D','S'], ['D','J'], ['D','I'], ['D','E'],
  ['E','I'], ['E','H'], ['E','G'], ['E','F'], ['F','G'], ['F','L'],
  ['F','M'], ['M','N'], ['N','O'], ['O','P'], ['P','Q'], ['Q','R'],
  ['R','S'], ['S','J'], ['J','I'], ['I','H'], ['H','G'], ['G','L'],
  ['L','M'], ['K','R'],  ['K','J'], ['K','H'], ['K','L'], ['K','N'],
  ['K','P'], 
]
```

To test, here is a plot of the graph

```
for edge in edges:
  ls = nodes[edge[0]]
  le = nodes[edge[1]]
  plt.plot([ls[0], le[0]], [ls[1],le[1]], color="blue")

for p in nodes:
  l = nodes[p]

  plt.text(l[0],l[1],p)
  plt.scatter(l[0], l[1], color="red")
```

[image: plotter graph]

Auxiliary functions. The first one gets the other node in an edge; the second one computes the distance between two nodes.

```
def getOther(node, edge):
  a,b = edge
  if node == a:
    return b
  else:
    return a

def getDistance(node1, node2):
  x1,y1 = nodes[node1]
  x2,y2 = nodes[node2]

  return np.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1- y2)**2)
```

Depth first graph search.

```
def getPaths(source, destination):
  pathsout = []
  stack = [source]
  while stack:
    path = stack.pop()
    node = path[-1]
    if node == destination:
      pathsout.append(path)

    dist = getDistance(node, destination)
    candidates = [getOther(node, edge) for edge in edges if node in edge]
    for c in candidates:
      if getDistance(c, destination) <= dist:
        stack.append(path + c )

  return set(pathsout) # transform into set to remove duplicates
```

Run simulation

```
print(f"n. paths from A to B: {len(getPaths('A','B'))}")
print(f"n. paths from A to C: {len(getPaths('A','C'))}")
print(f"n. paths from A to D: {len(getPaths('A','D'))}")
```

Results:

```
# paths from A to B: 5
# paths from A to C: 41
# paths from A to D: 121
```

## Paths

Print are the paths the beavers can follow

```
print(f"n. paths from A to B: {len(getPaths('A','B'))}")
print(' '.join(getPaths('A','B')) + '\n\n')
print(f"n. paths from A to C: {len(getPaths('A','C'))}")
print(' '.join(getPaths('A','C')) + '\n\n')
print(f"n. paths from A to D: {len(getPaths('A','D'))}")
print(' '.join(getPaths('A','D')))
```

Results:

```
n. paths from A to B: 5
AOPB ANOPB ANOB AOB AB


n. paths from A to C: 41
ANKJSC ANOPQC AOBPQC AOBQRC ANOBQRC AMNOPQC AMNKJSC AOPQRC ANOPQRC AMNKPQC AMNKJSRC AOBC AMNOBC ABPQRC AMNKPQRC AMLKRC AMNKRC ANOBQC AOBQC ANKRC AOPQC ABQC AMNOBQC AMLKJSC AMNOPQRC ANOBPQRC ANKJSRC AMLKPQC AMLKJSRC AMNOBQRC AMNOBPQC ANOBC ABC AOBPQRC ANKPQRC ANOBPQC ABPQC AMLKPQRC AMNOBPQRC ANKPQC ABQRC


n. paths from A to D: 121
AOPKHID ABOPKHID AMNKRSD ABONKHID AMLGHID AFGHID AFMLGEID AMNKHID AONKRSJD AFMLGHID AFMLKHIJD AFGEHID AOPQCRSJD AFLGEID ABONKRSJD AMLKHIJD ABONKJD ABPQCSJD AMLKJD AFMLKHID AFLKJD ABOPKHIJD ABQCSD ABCSD AMLKRSD AOPKRSJD ABCD AONKRSD AFMNKRSD AFLGEIJD ABPKRSJD AMLGEHIJD AFGED ABOPQRSJD ABQCSJD AOPQCRSD AFGEHIJD ANKHIJD ABOPKRSD AOPQRSD AFMLGEHID AMLGED AMNKRSJD ABQRSD AMLKHID AFMLKJD AFLGED ANKRSD AFLKHIJD AFMLGED AONKHID ABPKJD AMLGEIJD AFGHIJD AMLKRSJD AFLGEHID ABPKHIJD ABPQCRSJD AMLGEHID AFEIJD ABONKHIJD ABONKRSD ANKJD AOPKHIJD ABPQCRSD AFGEIJD AFEHID AMLGEID ABPQCSD ABPQCD ABQRSJD AMLGHIJD ABPKHID ABCRSD ABPQRSJD ABCRSJD ABQCRSJD ABOPQCSJD AFMLGEIJD ABOPKJD AMNKHIJD AONKHIJD AMNKJD AFEID AFLGHID AFLKRSJD ANKHID ANKRSJD AFMNKJD AFED ABQCRSD ABOPQCRSJD ABOPQRSD AOPKRSD AFGEID AFLGHIJD ABQCD AOPQCSD AFMLKRSD AONKJD AFEHIJD ABCSJD AFMNKHID ABPKRSD AOPQCD AOPKJD ABOPKRSJD AFMNKRSJD ABOPQCD AFMLKRSJD AFMLGEHIJD ABPQRSD AFLGEHIJD AFMNKHIJD ABOPQCRSD AFMLGHIJD AOPQRSJD AOPQCSJD AFLKHID ABOPQCSD AFLKRSD
```

Comment: Thank you.  This clears thing up for me.

Comment: Someone please check my A$\to$C beaver, if that is right I may tackle A$\to$D as well. The idea would be to build upon the paths from A$\to$C and add the few remaining ones.

Comment: No I'm miscounting the last additional paths. It should be all the ways he has to get to the center point; I'll give it a shot later.

Comment: To go from A to C he can first land to G, L, M, N, O, B. If he lands on G he can follow the paths: AMLGHIDJSC, AMLGHIDC, AMLGHIDSC, AMLGHIDSRC, AMLGHKJSC, AMLGHKJSRC, AMLGHKRC, AMLGHKPQC, AMLGHKPQRC.

Comment: No he cannot go through G because G is farther away from C than L.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo I am grateful for all your work! However, I need to clarify something very important! The beaver can't go directly from one point to another, unless there is a burrow (marked with a line segment)! Therefore, he can't go directly from O to K, or from K to Q etc because there is no line connecting these points! See, our beavers don't dig :)

Comment: I am getting 5, 41 and 121. Also in your paths, some were listed twice.

Comment: Ah yes you're right! I was tired and I didn't bother to check. I'll update the code asap.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! You are a genius!

Comment: There were some duplicate paths in A$\to$D only. The rest seem okay. I have changed the simulation to remove them.

Comment: Again, you have paths that include "OK", "KQ" etc, which are not permitted since there is no line connecting O with K or K with Q etc.

Comment: Aha I see, I had added edges between K and all the nodes around the center. I have removed the spurious edges and now I can confirm your finding!